# how can i freeze the execution of flex program till the pop up is not answered?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, popup

I m using flex. In my program on certain condition a pop up should come. In that pop up i edit some fields. On Pop up there are 2 buttons, Ok and Cancel. If Ok is pressed then the normal flow of the program should continue, else the further code should not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Set MODAL=trur while creating POPUP like

```
var titleWindow:TitleWindow
   = TitleWindow(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, TitleWindow,true));
 //setting modal=true i.e. 3rd parameter default value is false,
```

hopes that helps